# Unable to read data from the transport connection

Tags: vb.net

I am getting following exception:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was f orcibly closed by the remote
>   host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An e xisting connection
>   was forcibly closed by the remote host at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 s ize) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 s ize) at System.Net.DelegatedStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count) at System.Net.BufferedReadStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 coun t) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLines(SmtpReplyReader
>   caller, B oolean oneLine) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpReplyReaderFactory.ReadLine(SmtpReplyReader
>   caller) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host,
>   Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String
>   host, Int32 port) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) at
>   testEmail.Module1.Main() in E:\testEmail\testEmail\Module1.vb:line 17

Comment: This looks to be a firewall issue, or otherwise do you have permission to send through the smtp server you are using? Google for a free smtp server to see if that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this kind of error for different reasons. I found it helpful to enable exception sending (by enabling the serviceDebug tag with the attribute includeExceptionDetailInFaults set to true)

You'd have to add the behaviorConfiguration attribute to the service first

```
 <service behaviorConfiguration="blah" name="blahService" >
```

and after closing the services tag you have to add

```
<behaviors>
    <behavior name="blah">
           <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailsInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```